# How to realize select one but excluding the other in react IF condition?

Tags: reactjs, if-statement

So I wish to select "update" path inside a react component **if one data
's name is found**, then inside this **"if"** I have another "**if(a window.confirm)"**, if user confirm, then execute to finish update. Within this component I have regular **"add"** new data path parallel with **"update**" which as mentioned contains two nested **if**s conditions. I show you the code below. So far, seems none of the ifs works correctly. First if, after execution, keep running to **"add"** function, then the window.confirm, does not matter confirm or cancel, also does **"add"**. Coudl you tell how should I adjust ?

```
const addName = (event) => {
      
        event.preventDefault()

        const nameObj = {
          name: newName,
          number: newNumber,
          id: nanoid()
    
        }

        if (persons.find((person)=> person.name === newName)){
          const id = persons.find(person=>person.name===newName).id
          const changedPerson = {...nameObj, number: nameObj.number}
          if (window.confirm(`${newName} already there`)) {
            personService
            .update(id, changedPerson)
            .then(returnPerson=>{
              setPersons(persons.map(person => person.id === id ? person : returnPerson))
              setNewName('')
              setNewNumber('')
              return 
            })
          }
        }
        personService
        .create(nameObj)
        .then(returnPerson=>{
          setPersons(persons.concat(returnPerson))
          setNewName('')
          setNewNumber('')
        console.log('added', nameObj)
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

add a `return` before the end of the close `}` of the first `if`, if you choose not to add an `else`,

If you don't add a return (to exit the function), it will continue to execute `personService.create()`

---

You currently have a `return`, but that's to return the promise, not to return the function.

For example

```
 if (persons.find((person)=> person.name === newName)){
     .......// do something

     return; // you need the return here 

    } else {
       //codes here will not execute if you don't add the above return
    }

    //codes here will continue to execute if you don't add the above return
```